# Javascript - Display a different content if a checkbox is active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I'm trying to set up something in JQuery but at the moment I'm not really sure I'm doing it right.

To keep it simple, I would like to display 4 checkboxes. These checkboxes serve as filters. For the example, let's say the first checkbox is spring, the second is summer, the third is autumn and the fourth is winter.

When I check the "summer" box I would like some text to be displayed. If I tick the autumn one, another text is displayed. Basically, I would like to display different texts depending on what is ticked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv(winter) {
        var winter_list = document.getElementById("winter_list");
        winter_list.style.display = winter.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv(summer) {
        var summer_list = document.getElementById("summer_list");
        summer_list.style.display = summer.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>

<label for="checkWinter">
    <input type="checkbox" id="winter" onclick="ShowHideDiv(winter)" />
    Winter
</label>
<label for="checkSummer">
    <input type="checkbox" id="summer" onclick="ShowHideDiv(summer)" />
    Summer
</label>
<hr />


<!-- For Winter -->
<div id="winter_list" style="display: none">
<p>Text come here</p>
</div>


<!-- For Summer -->
<div id="summer_list" style="display: none">
<p>Text come here for summer</p>
</div>
```

If possible: Can we make it possible to tick more than one box?

I've been following tutorials on StackOverflow but so far without much success, as I haven't found anything in the genre of my same request.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to start working on your requirement one by one. If you get stuck at some point, please tyr tyo solve it yourself. If you are not able to achive it, please post a question with relavent code.

Comment: I also have try with this post [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery
My checkbox display, but when I click on the first or the second, the same text is displayed. And just added my code

Comment: @Moerip You uses standard javascript, but you tagged jquery. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: @Reporter If we can do that's in Javascript, I prefer in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in thinking of your code.

The function `ShowHideDiv()`does exists two times and Javascript overload it. Because your passed an undefined object, the browser choose one of them.

My Suggestion:

First step: Replace the function calls in your input fields by `<input type="checkbox" id="summer" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" />`. The parameter `this` passes the clicked object to target function.

Second step: Merge all of your function "ShowHideDiv" to one:

```
function ShowHideDiv(checkbox) {
   switch (checkbox.id)
   {
      case "summer":
            var summer_list = document.getElementById("summer_list");
             summer_list.style.display = summer.checked ? "block" : "none";
         break;
      case "winter":
          var winter_list = document.getElementById("winter_list");
                winter_list.style.display = winter.checked ? "block" : "none";
          break;
      default:
        //What ever you want do to
        break;
   }
}
```

The argument `checkbox.id` returns the value from attribute id of passed checkbox.

`Switch and case` is a smaller form of `if() else if() and else()`.

Answer (score 2):

First, give all your checkboxes an `id`.
You can then add `data-target` to the display texts for easy selection. Try this

```html
<label for="winter">
    <input type="checkbox" id="winter" onchange="ShowHideDiv(this)" />
    Winter
</label>
<label for="summer">
    <input type="checkbox" id="summer" onchange="ShowHideDiv(this)" />
    Summer
</label>
<hr />

<!-- Display text -->
<div>
    <p style="display: none" data-target="#winter">Text come here</p>
    <p style="display: none" data-target="#summer">Text come here for summer</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv(elem) {
        var target = document.querySelector('[data-target="#'+elem.id+'"]');
        target.style.display = elem.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, cleanest solution I could think of is this:

```js
const ShowHideDiv = function (check, season) {
  let el = document.getElementById(season);
  
  // hide element(s)
  el.classList.add('hidden');
  
  // Show element(s) if checked
  if(check.checked === true){
    el.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkWinter">
    <input id="checkWinter" type="checkbox" onchange="ShowHideDiv(this, 'winter')" />
    Winter
</label>
<label for="checkSummer">
    <input id="checkSummer" type="checkbox" onchange="ShowHideDiv(this, 'summer')" />
    Summer
</label>
<label for="checkSpring">
    <input id="checkSpring" type="checkbox" onchange="ShowHideDiv(this, 'spring')" />
    Spring
</label>
<hr />


<!-- For Winter -->
<div class="hidden" id="winter">
  <p>Text come here  for winter</p>
</div>


<!-- For Summer -->
<div class="hidden" id="summer">
  <p>Text come here for summer</p>
</div>


<!-- For Spring -->
<div class="hidden" id="spring">
  <p>Text come here for spring</p>
</div>
```

It works without changes for 2, 3 or 4 seasons.